# How can i solve syntax error during making webapp?

Tags: python, django

im working with django and making webapp now this has occurred

```
def Notes(generic.DetailView):
                 ^
Error invalid syntax
```

Function name:NotesDetaiView

Comment: Yes, this is not valid django. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I'm doing it like what it is in a YouTube video
https://youtu.be/XvU0QXqDQ1Y
1:10:45

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this. Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview).

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from .models import Notes # or other location

class NotesDetailView(DetailView):
        
    model = Notes
        
    # rest of code
```